# Java regex to check if a pattern exists

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find whether a pattern exists in a string.

Pattern I want to check is:

> String starting with space or "#",
>   then with specific string "value1" followed by space or tab,
>   then "value2" and again space or tab,
>   ends with "value3".

Here a sample string to check:

```
String str = "#  value1   values2 value3";
```

I tried the following *regular expression*, but it did't work:

```
str.matches("^\\s+#\\s+value1\\s+value2\\s+value3");
```

The above pattern always returns me `false`. Please help with regular expression.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to match a single space at the start or double space?

Comment: want to match space or tab - \\s+

Comment: You said you want to match whether the string starts with a `#` or a `space`. But the string you posted starts with both: - `# value1 values2 value3`. It has both a `#` followed by a space.

Comment: Did you realize that `String str = "# value1 values2 value3"` got an S in values2 and that's because your regex is not working? (apart of \\s#, use @RohitJain one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: -

```
str.matches("^[ #]value1\\s+value2\\s+value3$");
```

`[ #]` - matches a space or #

`\\s+` - matches 1 or more spaces. So, it would match a space or tab

**NOTE**: - You have `values2` instead of `value2` in your string.

Also, your example string you posted, has both a `space` and a `#` at the starting. But you said the string starts with a `space` or a `#`. So, it will match your string, if you remove that space after the first `#`, or your `#` before your space, which is according to what you wrote.

If you want to match a `space` and a `#` at the starting of your string, as in your current `String` you posted. You need to use this regex: -

```
str.matches("^[ #]\\svalue1\\s+value2\\s+value3$");
```

Comment: u think the asker needs to match `" value1 values2 value3"`, because your regex will not match that.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ah sorry. I got confused. Actually OP wrote something else, and his example string says something else.

Comment: @RohitJain  Did you know that you can click on you score to actually see whether or not any downvotes have been made on your answer.  I would assume not since your answer has recieved none, yet you seem to assume that i downvoted

Comment: @JanDvorak. OP has this string: - `# value1 values2 value3` and said he want to start with a space or #, so I thought may be he wants a space and # or 2 spaces.

Comment: Perhaps he means `#` or space or both

Comment: @SamIam. I of course can't know who downvoted. But the moment you posted that comment, there was a down vote on the answer. But later on, it changed. Sorry if that bothered you.

Comment: @JanDvorak. Well, then the question is confusing. Let's see, if it doesn't work. OP will ask for change. then I'll change accordingly. :)

Comment: There was no downvote, ever. I temporarily removed my upvote because the answer didn't match the requirements.

Comment: @JanDvorak. Ah! well, I assumed that only as downvote. Sorry though. It may happen. :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can tell you right now that that regex WILL fail for that input because it requires whitespace before the `#`

try

```
str.matches("^#?\\s+value1\\s+value2\\s+value3$");
```

that regex should match `"# value1 value2 value3"` or `" value1 value2 value3"` with variable amounts of whitespace

Comment: requirement: 'starting with space or "#"'

Comment: @JanDvorak  it does start with a space or #

Comment: @JanDvorak  does that `\\s+` after the `#?` not require a space in order to be matched?

Comment: `\\s+` always requires a space in order to match.

Comment: @JanDvorakn then the regex I posted will only match strings that start with a `#` or a space won't it.

Comment: No. It will require a whitespace to be there.

Comment: @JanDvorak isn't that the requirement?

Comment: Perhaps not, but let's say it's within tolerance. Make a formal edit and I'll lift the downvote. I assumed you didn't know what your regex was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(\s+|\s?#\s?).*value1.*(\s+|\t).*value2.*(\s+|\t).*value3.*`
It works even if you have whitespaces anywhere.